# What causes GitHub to show a commit as being committed by one user *with* another user

Tags: git, github

Take a look at [this commit](https://github.com/typings/typings/commit/abea10b5787e1a18634d5f37bb2fa56550c32fd1) for example.

[image]

Notice how two users are shown here, both @unional and @blakeembrey.

What causes this?

---

**EDIT** Some further research:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:typings/typings.git
$ cd typings
$ git show abea10b5787e1a18634d5f37bb2fa56550c32fd1
commit abea10b5787e1a18634d5f37bb2fa56550c32fd1
Author: Homa Wong <homawong@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu May 26 09:47:58 2016 -0700

    Update `bundle` help (#557)

diff --git a/src/bin-bundle.ts b/src/bin-bundle.ts
index 8e6dd26..2af3599 100644
--- a/src/bin-bundle.ts
+++ b/src/bin-bundle.ts
@@ -5,11 +5,10 @@ import { bundle } from 'typings-core'

 export function help () {
   return `
-typings bundle --out <directory>
+typings bundle --out <filepath>

 Options:
-  [--out|-o] <directory> The bundled output directory
-  [--name] <name>        Bundle module name
+  [--out|-o] <filepath>  The bundled output file path
   [--global|-G]          Bundle as an global definition
 `
 }
```

Interestingly there's only one user ([unional](https://github.com/unional)) mentioned in the commit. Is this some additional metadata stored within GitHub?

---

**EDIT 2** Actually it seems that `git show` doesn't give the full patch metadata. Using `gitk` I see this instead:

```
Author: Homa Wong <homawong@gmail.com>  2016-05-26 17:47:58
Committer: Blake Embrey <hello@blakeembrey.com>  2016-05-26 17:47:58
Parent: b79fd3f0f9af245a790717dcb5493fb49db2788d (Update README.md to add example of dt install (#547))
Branches: master, remotes/origin/master
Follows: v1.0.4
Precedes: 

    Update `bundle` help (#557)
```

Here we see a different author and committer. It seems that this was a PR that was rebased rather than merged.

Comment: author vs committer

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, I don't believe that's it. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a <strike>merge</strike> [squash commit](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits). When one merges a pull request/branch by combining all commits into one big commit, those who:

- Created the pull request
- Committed to the branch that will be merged
- Merged the pull request

will appear as committers on the created commit. Apparently the one who creates the pull request gets to have his/her identification in the commit, and the ones who made the individual commits and squashed them are stored as metadata.

In this case:

- unional is the one who created the pull request and made the only commit
- blakeembrey is the one who merged the pull request

Comment: If it's a merge commit, why does it only have one parent?

Comment: @DrewNoakes Wait, [it's not a conventional merge!](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)